# change request uri before set controller and action in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, controller, request, uri, action

I am doing a web in **Zend Framework**. I wanna it for being multilanguage so in the structure controller/action I wanna add a uri parameter like this:

```
domain.com/en/controller/action
```

But obviusly Zend try to get controller with name `en`. How can I modify the `requestUri` before Zend set the controller name and the action name?

Thanks

Comment: Dont modify the URI... [reconfigure the routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own routes for this, begin with something like this in your application.ini:

```
resources.router.routes.default.route = ":language/:controller/:action"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.action = "index"
```

More information on the Zend website: [The Standard Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Comment: I were more specific at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299325/properly-use-of-languages-in-zend-framework

Comment: Why do you open a second question instead of updating this one?